# How can I reshape (120, 100, 100) shaped image data to (120, 10000) shape to undersample using "imblearn" library of Python?

Tags: python, imbalanced-data, imblearn

I am working with **imblearn** library of **Python** for undersampling.

Necessary code:

```
undersample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')
X_under, y_under = undersample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Here **X** is my image dataset & of **(120, 100, 100) shape** and **y** is images' labels which is of **(120,) shape**. I am getting an error here.
But if I give **X** of **shape (x_value, y_value)** then it works.
Is there any way I can convert **(120, 100, 100) shape** of image data to **(120, 10000)** shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the image data into an numpy array and then reshape, that would solve it

```
import numpy as np
# assuming X is the image data of shape (120,100,100)
X = np.asarray(image)
X_reshape = X.reshape(120,10000)
```

Comment: Also you should reframe your question to how to reshape rather than how to unsample, since that's what the question is about.